# AWS CloudWatch alarm actions once, triggers lambda 3 times

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have a standard `CW alarm --> SNS --> Lambda` set up. The alarm console shows that it executed 1 successful action to the SNS topic. But on the lambda console it triggered 3 times, with the same request ID and payload? Only the execution times are different. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description matches the behavior of [retry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#delivery-policies-for-protocols) submissions from SNS to Lambda. Basically, SNS will try to **retry 3 times** without any delay on a failed submission.

Thus it seems that for some reason your lambda is failing and SNS **immediately retries**. Please inspect cloudwatch logs for possible error messages.